# Informix 12.0 — Script reversibility

Tags: database, informix

The problem is, I have a script, S, which I run on a database.  Is there a script, T, that when run, returns the database to the first point — the state before S ran?

My work so far has been:

First method:

```
#add to start of S:
BEGIN WORK TXN1
SAVEPOINT TO TXN1
...  

#T: 
ROLLBACK WORK TO SAVEPOINT TXN1
```

Second method:

All methods based on table and schema backup.

Unfortunately, for a thousand and one reasons, this solution is not suitable.
Can anyone answer that, in principle, the problem is solvable or in some cases, S is not reversible?

Comment: Ummm, not quite sure to understand your question but you can find some info about savepoints with Informix in the following link (https://informix.hcldoc.com/12.10/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fids_sqs_2009.htm).
Basically you need to use something like `BEGIN WORK;` `SAVEPOINT S1;` `CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 int);` `SAVEPOINT S2;` `CREATE TABLE t2 (c1 int);` `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT S1;` to rollback specific operations

Comment: Maybe you need to look at backup and point-in-time (PIT) restore.  It depends on whether what you need to restore is done inside a single transaction (or a savepoint within a transaction), or whether you need to work over multiple transactions, possibly with multiple sessions (a transaction is pretty much tied to a single session).  If you need to work across transactions and sessions, then you can make a backup at the start of work, and recover to the PIT.  However, any backup/restore is going to undo any parallel work that isn't part of your work. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ You might be able to do table-level restores — but again, if anyone else is working on the same tables, segregating their work from your work, is going to be, at best, non-trivial (close to 'not doable').

Comment: To answer your question "Is there a guaranteed way to write a script T that reverses the changes made by script S?", the answer is "No, in general".  Some scripts may be reversible, but scripts in general are not reliably reversible.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: that is answer